# I get setImageBitmap(Bitmap) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])

Tags: android, bitmap, android-sqlite

I am getting this error `The method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])` when trying to load the image from SQlite database.

What i did was this

Convert image to byte[]:

```
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
imageData = baos.toByteArray();
```

then save image to Database:

```
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE, imageData);
```

Then retrieve image to display in imageview:

```
byte[] img = null;
....
img = arg1.getBlob(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE));
....
img = markerIcon.setImageBitmap(imageData);
```

But under `setImageBitmap` i get the error

What do i need to do to resolve this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDITED CODE**

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    int locationCount = 0;
    double lat=0;
    double lng=0;
    float zoom=0;
    byte[] img = null;
    locationCount = arg1.getCount();
    arg1.moveToFirst();

    for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

        lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));
        lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));
        zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));
        img = arg1.getBlob(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE));
        thePoint = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        drawMarker(thePoint);
        arg1.moveToNext();
    }

    if(locationCount>0){
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length);
        img = markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168): Process: com.example.mainapp, PID: 8168
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at com.example.mainapp.Map.onLoadFinished(Map.java:338)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at com.example.mainapp.Map.onLoadFinished(Map.java:1)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:4    27)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:395)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at  android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:104)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:73)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:35)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:223)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:461)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask.java:47)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:474)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-23 16:39:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(8168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: From a quick google of "java setImageBitmap" I found that _setImageBitmap_ than a _Bitmap_ as argument. Simply convert your _byte[]_ to _Bitmap_

Comment: Where are you initialising imageData in this code. Your imageData seems to be Null as There is not initialisation of it and as you mentioned to get it from the database, I cant see anything for doing that sort of thing in onLoadFinished().

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the `byte[]` back into a `Bitmap`, via `BitmapFactory` and [its `decodeByteArray()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29).

Comment: Okay, would i then put it before the `img = markerIcon.setImageBitmap(imageData)`  and use `imageData.decodeByteArray(....)`? Sorry for the stupid question, but i amtrying to understand what i need to do.

Comment: Checkout my answer below. setImageBitmap() is a void method. There is no point writing img = markerIcon.setImageBitmap(). After 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length);
Simply put:
markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to set a byte[] array as the argument instead of a Bitmap value. You can convert the byte[] to a Bitmap by using the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length);
```

Then use this `bitmap` as the argument for your `setBitmap()` method.

Comment: Cool thanks but the when i do that i get this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to byte[]`

Comment: Do not use img = markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap); setImageBitmap() is a void method. So, simply use:

markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: If i do that the the app crashes with error `NullPointerException` when launching at line 338 which is this line `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length);`  Am i saving it correctly into my database?

Comment: @Newbie: It is not possible for that specific line to have a `NullPointerException`. Conceivably, with invalid `imageData`, there might be a `NullPointerException` *inside* the implementation of `decodeByteArray()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Oh okay,  I have edited my question with the errors I am getting

Comment: @Newbie: Your code will not compile AFAICT. The output of `getBlob()` is `byte[]`, and the output of `setImageBitmap()` is `void`. Yet, you are assigning the output of `setImageBitmap()` to a `byte[]` named `img`.

Comment: @CommonsWare:  Okay cool i understand what you are saying but would you be kind enough to show me how i can resolve this :-( ?